# No puedo editar las publicaciones

Tags: soporte, ediciones-sugeridas

Al intentar editar una publicación en SOes, me aparece un mensaje, en vez de la caja para editar.

> Ediciones sugeridas
>
> Estás temporalmente inhabilitado para sugerir ediciones. Por favor revise su [historial de ediciones](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/13558/arteze?tab=activity&sort=suggestions)

Algo parecido ocurre cuando intento ver la cola de revisiones.

> Se rechazaron demasiadas de tus ediciones.

Le hice caso al primer mensaje, intenté ver mi historial de revisiones, pero mi última edición rechazada fue del 21 de Enero. Ya pasó bastante tiempo, y no se restaura, no le encuentro explicación.

PD: Lo único que creo es que algún moderador se enojó, porque justo por esos días me borraron una respuesta duplicada en meta.

Comment: Revisé las sugerencias de ediciones que te rechazaron y no veo motivo alguno... La [fórmula](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/92337/304899) para que se dispare el bloqueo es `(rechazadas - (aprobadas / 3)) >= 5` en un rango de 7 días y claramente no sucede eso... Y ahora voy a decir lo obvio que todos sabemos pero vale la pena mencionar: tus ediciones son excelentes y ojalá hubiese más usuarios que estén editando de esa forma (uno puede o no estar de acuerdo con algún formato, pero no con la edición en general), y sería bueno que un moderador revise este tema para corregirlo cuanto antes.

Comment: @Mariano Ya está solucionado.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Se ha levantado el bloqueo automático que tenias aplicado.

He revisado todas tus ediciones sugeridas recientes y no he visto motivo alguno para que se bloquee.

He visto en tu perfil que la sanción aplicada era automática por el sistema y hasta el 8 de marzo pero no veo motivo aparente.

> Lo único que creo es que algún moderador se enojó, porque justo por esos días me borraron una respuesta duplicada en meta.

Nunca un moderador va a aplicar algún tipo de sanción sin comunicarse con el usuario en cuestión. Eso te lo puedo garantizar. No ha pasado y espero que no pase nunca. Es importante que si se aplica una sanción se explique con detalle el porqué y sobretodo el cómo corregir la situación.

Comment: Nótese que borrar una pregunta o respuesta no es una sanción.

Comment: @JoseAntonioDuraOlmos no entiendo tu aclaración. A qué te refieres?